# Знаки препинания, кавычки

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте, и два вопроса.

Как верно расставить кавычки в предложении, если первая буква К — буквица?
*«Кто поджег дом? В котором часу вспыхнул пожар?*»* — *вот 
вопросы, которые все задавали*.

Как верно расставить знаки препинания? *Вот изображение человека немилосердного: «Что может быть ужаснее и бесстыднее, чем лицо этого негодяя?"* 
или без кавычек?

Comment: Теперь уже вообще не вижу, о чем исходно спрашивали.

Answer (score 1):

1. Дело не в буквице, а в том, считать ли  вопросы чужой речью. Можно оформить как прямую речь - так, как у Вас.

А я бы предпочла без кавычек, не как прямую речь, а как простые вопросы, они же могут передавать только суть, а не всю  фразу без изменения, и потом часто кавычки не ставят, если это могут сказать все, без привязки к какому-то автору.
Кто поджег дом? В котором часу вспыхнул пожар? — вот вопросы, которые все задавали.

2. Не вижу причин ставить кавычки и во втором случае. Нужен контекст, чтобы понять, чужая это речь или просто авторское размышление.

Вот изображение человека немилосердного: что может быть ужаснее и бесстыднее, чем лицо этого негодяя?

Насчёт двоеточия  тоже неоднозначно. Возможно и двоеточие как авторский знак, похожий на двоеточие в газетных заголовках типа Бажов: читатель и книголюб. Вторая часть раскрывает содержание первой, но экспрессивно:"Вот изображение человека немилосердного: что может быть ужаснее и бесстыднее, чем лицо этого негодяя?"(Лицо человека немилосердного: ужасное и бесстыдное).

Возможно здесь и тире - оценка как следствие, но лучше бы поставить точку,ведь сначала идёт констатация факта, а потом к нему отношение - это разные мысли.

Answer (score 1):

1) **БСП**: Кто поджег дом, в  котором часу вспыхнул пожар — вот вопросы, которые все задавали. Тире перед указательной частицей ВОТ, вторая часть имеет значение обобщения.

**Пример:** Может ли в принципе существовать такая мораль, каково её содержание, необходима ли она человечеству ― вот вопросы, которые мы попытаемся обсудить в данной работе.

2) **БСП**: Вот изображение человека немилосердного: что может быть ужаснее и бесстыднее, чем лицо этого негодяя?  Вторая часть поясняет первую, поэтому ставится двоеточие.

Answer (score 0):

Наталия! Обще правило всегда и всюду одно. Обе кавычки должны быть одинакового рисунка. Кавычки - знак парный. Можете делать ёлочки, можете лапочки, но никогда их не смешивайте.

> Вот изображение человека немилосердного: что может быть ужаснее и
>   бесстыднее, чем лицо этого негодяя

Двоеточие совершенно не оправданно. Если уж так надо написать в одной фразе, поставьте точку с запятой.

Comment: В конце предложения вопросит.знак, тогда кавычки не нужны и так будет ли верно:                                                                                       Вот изображение человека немилосердного; что может быть ужаснее и бесстыднее, чем лицо этого негодяя?

Comment: Подождите. Кавычки-то то у вас что обозначают? Это цитата? Если да, то они, конечно, все равно нужны, хоть там десять вопросительных. А если не цитата, тогда зачем они вообще?

Comment: это предложение входит в большой текст цитаты, кавычки елочки открыты в начале и в конце этой цитаты, но в данном предложении считаю, что не нужны кавычки, тогда как верно будет, поставить после "немилосердного" точку с запятой? Вот так верно ли: Вот изображение человека немилосердного; что может быть ужаснее и бесстыднее, чем лицо этого негодяя?    и без внутренних кавычек.